# How to do one to one hibernate mapping, using a non-primary key as references

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to do a XML Hibernate mapping for a one to one relation for tables

User ( UserId, Name, StatusId)
Status (StatusId, StatusName)

i tried this that i found on the forum

Under User.hbm.xml

```
  <many-to-one class="Status" name="statusid" property-ref="statusid">
    <column name="statusname" />
  </many-to-one>
```

and becoz of this i got this error

SEVERE: Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NullPointerException
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[default]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

When I use the PK as the reference, i don't receive this error ..

Can anybody please explain what does the property means and why am i getting this error?
PS: I'm in a learning stage, please help >.<

Comment: could you post the full stack trace of the error maybe?

Comment: In the title it says 'one to one'. I guess you meant a many-to-one? Unless you want each user to have a different status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you dont have something special the following mapping should work. Nevertheless its always helpful to have the **full stacktrace**.

```
  <many-to-one class="Status" name="statusid" column="StatusId" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, you really want to join on `User.statusid = Status.statusname`? This means that statusname is an alternate key for Status.

In your property-ref you need to set the property of the Status object that you refer to.
See [Associations on Alternate Keys](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/example-mappings.html#example-mappings-association-alternatekeys):

```
<many-to-one class="Status" name="statusid" property-ref="statusname"/>
```