# Map two columns without Primary Key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I've got 2 tables - Person and Requests.

```
Person (id is PK):  
id  name  req_id
Requests(id is PK):  
id rid
```

In java:

```
@Entity
public class Person{
@Id
Int id;
String name;
String req_id;
...}    

@Entity
public class Requests{
@Id
Int id;
String rid;
...}`
```

What I want to do is to map (OneToOne) rid with req_id.
Unfortunately, I cannot use @SecondaryTable because the tables are not mapped by primary keys.
I would appreciate any help...

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand exactly why you require that but what ever this may be help you [How to do one to one hibernate mapping, using a non-primary key as references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713863/how-to-do-one-to-one-hibernate-mapping-using-a-non-primary-key-as-references)